# how to get hierarchyin SQL server ,TSQL,SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table

```
ref_id parent_id
A        B
B        C
C        D
D        D
X        Y
Y        Y
P        Q
Q        R
R        R
```

output
hierarchy

```
A
B
C
D
X
Y
P
Q
R
```

if ref_id = parent_id then its top of the tree i.e parent of all.

Comment: How do we know that `A` is the true root node and not some other top level node, such as `X` ?

Comment: A is not root the down the hierarchy

Comment: this scenario  is little different not like normal tree structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
WITH HIER_CTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: get root nodes 
    SELECT ref_id, parent_id, 1 AS lvl,
           -- Use ROW_NUMBER() to assign a unique ID to each root node 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ref_id) AS rn
    FROM mytable
    WHERE ref_id = parent_id

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member: get node of next level
    SELECT t.ref_id, t.parent_id, h.lvl + 1 AS lvl, rn
    FROM mytable AS t
    INNER JOIN HIER_CTE AS h ON h.ref_id = t.parent_id
    WHERE t.ref_id <> t.parent_id
)
SELECT ref_id
FROM HIER_CTE
ORDER BY rn, lvl DESC
```

**Output:**

```
ref_id
------
A
B
C
D
P
Q
R
X
Y
```

Comment: but thanks for quick replay , CTE can cause max recursion sometime

Comment: @Gajanan It works with the sample data provided. You need to provide additional info so that I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: i cannot able to provide ids its business critical but yes ids are not A,B,C this is just for example ids are like TXY-45896513,UTX-85962357 etc order by not work in this case

Comment: Can we do it using loop ? or joins CTE is taking lot of time

Comment: @Gajanan You need recursion in order to get the hierarchy. So, CTE is your best bet as far as performance is concerned. I tried to answer the question posted. Your actual use case seems to be different, so, I'm afraid I can't help you on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314019/hierarchical-query-match-with-multiple-tables-its-challenging/50314105#50314105

Comment: this is correct scenario - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50314019/hierarchical-query-match-with-multiple-tables-its-challenging/50314105#50314105